# What will happen if I supply greater than 1.1V to analogue inputs if analogReference set to INTERNAL?

Tags: analogread, adc

I am reading a 50Hz AC voltage using the analogue inputs.

If I set the analogReference() to INTERNAL, meaning 1.1V on the Arduino Uno, what will happen if a voltage greater than 1.1V is supplied to the pin? Will the board be damaged? If not, what value will the ADC give?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You will read 1023.

The limit of the voltage is not the reference voltage but the chip supply voltage - so 5v on a 5v board.